# Is it okay to use random OpenVPN config files?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I notice that there are sites on the internet that offer free VPN services via OpenVPN. Is there any danger in downloading and trying the .ovpn files that they offer for download?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A VPN endpoint is able to read and manipulate all your traffic (a Tor exit node too). Thus using some .ovpn file you just found on the internet means that you offer all your traffic to some unknown party for easy sniffing and manipulation. This includes sniffing passwords, injecting advertisements or injecting malware.

> Is it okay ... ?

If you are used to just use any random free WLAN you can find then there would not be much more of a problem to use some random free VPN endpoint too. I myself prefer it to be more secure but others might prefer that it is free.

Answer (score 4):

Based on a blog post responding to your question I guess it's not OK even for the file itself, which can contain remote code execution instructions, not talking about a third-party able to sniff your internet traffic.

https://medium.com/tenable-techblog/reverse-shell-from-an-openvpn-configuration-file-73fd8b1d38da